# Download JPEG from Amazon S3 Bucket results in 0 byte file

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, imagedownload

I can upload a JPEG file with no problems to the bucket from a Laravel 8 controller. I then want to download the same file from a route (no controller), and the file is downloaded but its 0 bytes in length. I'm not sure why because the file uploaded is public and I have never encountered this before. This is what I use to upload a JPEG to the bucket:

```
            $sourceOriginal=Image::make($request->file('file'))
                ->resize(1920, null, function($constraint) 
                {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                })
                ->encode('jpg', 80);

            $rootTarget='dev/'.$filename;
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($rootTarget, $sourceOriginal->stream(), 'public');
```

I've tried two different ways to download the file:

```
$the_filename='https://xxxx-s3-demo.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/uxQ6fwwxY68n6EQCQhfm1Mw20pNrJ9D76QZqlmyw.jpg';

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type'=> 'application/jpeg',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'. $the_filename .'"',
        ];

    return response()->make(Storage::disk('s3')->get($the_filename), 200, $headers);

# second method to download the file
Storage::disk('public')->put($another_filename, Storage::disk('s3')->get($the_filename));
```

As I said, no issues uploading the file. Only when wanting to download it. Does anyone have any suggestions? The file can be viewed publically from the S3 bucket as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need the relative URL of the file, not the whole link. because you're using disk

Comment: Garry, you are spot on. Well done, and thanks.